# Validation screams my html is not valid but in my opinion it is

Tags: html, formatting

A moment ago I tried to use Prettyfier from VS Code but it turns out my html code was badly formatted. To me it is perfect in every way but any other web prettyfier also protested. Even intellisense points that my li end tag has also its beginning and points it. Where is my mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        <title>A Meaningful Page Title</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />

    </head>
    <body class="d-flex flex-column">
        <header>
            <nav
                class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light border-bottom bg-light parent"
            >
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
                <button
                    class="navbar-toggler"
                    type="button"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                >
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 d-flex">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Feature</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Register</a>
              </li>
            </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Note, too, that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags including `<link>`

Answer (score 2):

List items cannot be direct children of other list items. You have this pattern in the markup: `li.ml-auto > li.nav-item` which is invalid HTML.

The [permitted parents of a list item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#technical_summary:%7E:text=An%20%3Cul%3E%2C%20%3Col%3E%2C%20or%20%3Cmenu%3E%20element.) are:

> An `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>` element.

That error message isn't very clear, but that's what is tripping the validator up.